# Python script behaves differently when there is a function definition

Tags: python, aravis

I'm running a script from a Linux terminal with Python 3.6.8 and the script started failing when I tried to expand it with a function definition. I whittled it down to the basics and found that the device fails to connect when there is a function definition followed by a print statement in the code, but not when there's a print statement followed by a function definition.

This code successfully connects to (and disconnects from) the device:

```py
import DeviceInterface

device_class = DeviceInterface.Device()

print()
def dummy_function_that_does_nothing():
    pass

with device_class:
    pass
```

This code, which swaps the function definition and print statement, gives a device connection error:

```py
import DeviceInterface

device_class = DeviceInterface.Device()

def dummy_function_that_does_nothing():
    pass
print()

with device_class:
    pass
```

These examples are the exact file contents of the scripts being run (nothing added or omitted for this post). The DeviceInterface module is a ctypes wrapper around a C-based .so library. That library uses Aravis v0.6.4. The connection failure is caused by a null pointer being returned from a call to arv_camera_new().

I would expect no difference between the 2 versions of code above. There seems to be something deeper going on in Python or Linux libraries that I don't understand.

Why would there be different behavior when the print() comes before the function definition, rather than after? I have workarounds, so my question is not centered around how to get my code working, but rather to understand at a low level why there would be a difference in the way Python is working. I was shocked that there would be a difference between these 2 versions of code.

### Reproducibility

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to reproduce the problem without a library I do not have rights to distribute. I'm hoping someone stumbles on this that knows how Python would behave differently when there's a function definition followed by a print statement (vs a print statement followed by a function definition). If I understood the difference between the 2 versions of code I could likely come up with a more generic way to reproduce the problem.

### Other things I've tried

- I've inserted delays in various places, but none had an effect on whether the device successfully connected, so it doesn't seem to be a timing issue as I originally suspected.
- I tried running both versions a number of times, and the problem has been very repeatably linked to the order of the function definition and the print statement (as opposed to being able to randomly connect).
- If I remove the print statement entirely, it succeeds regardless of where I put the function definition.
- I thought it might have to do with garbage collection killing a socket. I tried disabling the garbage collection with gc.disable() at the start of the script, but it didn't change the behavior.
- This code, which adds an additional function definition, successfully connects:

```py
import DeviceInterface

device_class = DeviceInterface.Device()

def dummy_function_that_does_nothing():
    pass
print()
def dummy_function_that_does_nothing_again():
    pass

with device_class:
    pass
```

- This code, which adds an additional function definition and another print statement, fails to connect:

```py
import DeviceInterface

device_class = DeviceInterface.Device()

def dummy_function_that_does_nothing():
    pass
print()
def dummy_function_that_does_nothing_again():
    pass
print()

with device_class:
    pass
```

- Changing the print statement to print(flush=True) or print(sys.stderr) did not change the functionality. However, print(end="") caused the problem to go away.
- Running python with unbuffered stdin/stdout/stderr (python3 -u odd_behavior_test.py) caused the failure to go away.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue without further information.

Comment: Does your function name mask/shadow another name in your program?

Comment: No, the function name is unique. Just in case, I changed the function name to a bunch of random letters, but no changes there.

Comment: Might have to do with how python handles global vars. I usually declare mine at the top of the file above any function definitions. Does error occur if func def is after instantiation of devices and device_classes?

Comment: Interesting point. If I move the function definition below the devices and device_classes lines (just above the print statement), it still fails. However, If I move the function definition to just after the print statement, it succeeds. Additionally, if I remove the print statement entirely, it succeed regardless of where I put the function definition. I will have to look into how the global variables vary between the examples. Thanks @ekmcd.

Comment: Does it help to put your script inside a main function, if \_\_name\_\_=='\_\_main\_\_': main()

Comment: @ekmcd "Might have to do with how python handles global vars." => there's nothing special with "how python handles global vars", and definitly nothing that would cause such an issue. And FYI, functions ARE global variables (well, those defined at the top-level that is).

Comment: @EmbedKa how is this code executed exactly ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm executing it from an xfce4-terminal using: python3 odd_behavior_test.py. The import at the top is a ctypes-based wrapper around a .so library.

Comment: @EmbedKa Uhu, ok, so nothing special here either - I kind of suspected this was actually executed by some special embedded interpreter or something like that... BTW you may want to edit your question to add this information too. At this point, the only "hypothesis" I can think of is that something in this proprietary layer is playing havoc with the CPython runtime, but that's only because there's absolutely nothing else here that could explain such a misbehaviour.

Comment: My guess is your file has some unprintable characters in it, maybe a mixture of unix and windows-style line endings, and that this means that some lines following the function definition are parsed as being inside the function, and therefore never executed. My theory is the `with device_class` never works, but sometimes it isn't even running because its inside a function. Can you try changing the `print()` lines to `print(1)`, `print(2)` and so on to see which print statements are actually running? You could also try typing out the files out again by hand to see if the behaviour still differs.